# autosave main scss file instead of having to save it manually

Tags: javascript, css, sass, visual-studio-code, live-sass-compiler

My folder structure is as follows

[image]

I am using 'live sass compiler' in vscode to watch files. But every time I update other scss files like _globals.scss I have to manually save style.scss for the changes to reflect. Is there a work-around to auto save style.scss instead of having to save it manually.

my settings.json for live sass compiler are as follows:

```
{
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.fontSize": 18,
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "workbench.editorAssociations": {
    "*.ipynb": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb"
  },
  "editor.renderWhitespace": "none",
  "liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": [],

  "liveSassCompile.settings.excludeList": ["**/node_modules/**", ".vscode/**"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems bizare. Anything with a leading underscore should compile all files. Do you still have the issue on [my active fork](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=glenn2223.live-sass)?